# R: como transformar em data somente o ano (quatro dígito) em um data frame?

Tags: r, data

tenho um data frame com a coluna abaixo. Eu gostaria de transformar os anos (com 4 dígitos) em datas (as.Date). A ideia seria manter somente os anos mesmo. Tentei algumas soluções que vi por aí, mas ainda não consegui. Sou iniciante no R e estou achando essa parte de transformar em datas muito difícil. Alguma dica? Grato!

```
summary(CPU$A0252)
     1945          1961          1964          1966          1970 
        1             1             1             2             1 
     1971          1972          1973          1980          1981 
        1             1             1             1             3 
     1982          1983          1984          1986          1987 
        1             1             2             3             4 
     1988          1989          1990          1991          1992 
        1             4             6            11             5 
     1993          1994          1995          1996          1997 
       13             6            11            14            23 
     1998          1999          2000          2001          2002 
        7            12            12            20            19 
     2003          2004          2005          2006          2007 
       58            30            69           223           201 
     2008          2009      Ignorado            NA Não aplicável 
      113            71            92             5          4520
```

Comment: Você quer fazer isso aqui: 

>hoje <- Sys.Date()
>format(hoje, format = "%Y")
[1] "2018"

Comment: Então no R se você tentar gerar  tipo Date,  setando somente o ano ele vai pegar uma data aleatória. Para isso você tem que usar o format que da certo.

Answer (score 1):

Transformando seu data frame:

```
str <- c("16/01/2018", "16/01/2019")
datas <- as.Date(str, "%d/%m/%Y")
datas
```

A saída por padrão é essa abaixo:

```
[1] "2018-01-16" "2019-01-16"
```

Formatando para ano de 4 dígitos:

```
format(datas, format = "%Y")
[1] "2018" "2019"
```

Obrigando você usar o format(), sempre que precisei manipular em R sempre usei essa função.

```
dataAno <- format(datas, format = "%Y")
```

E se você tentar forçar as.Date(dataAno, "%d/%m/%Y") passando somente o ano, mesmo que você coloque todos os parâmetros  você vai obter:

```
[1] NA NA
```

Sempre que precisar de um help, comando help(as.Date);

Têm esses dois sites ótimas  referências  em R:

https://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html

https://www.r-bloggers.com/date-formats-in-r/

Comment: Muito obrigado alxwca! As dicas foram valiosas. É a solução que mais chegou perto do que eu queria. Mas quando eu uso o "format", os dados mudam de "Date" para "chr" novamente. Isso não aconteceu com vc?

Comment: Sim,  mas como você quer trabalhar só com Ano isso vai acontecer. A não ser que tenha uma biblioteca que eu desconheça

Comment: Qual a finalidade de manipular o Ano, você quer somar, ou somente para listar?

Comment: Quero montar um gráfico de série temporal. Não é necessário ter a coluna das datas como "Date"? Eu estava imaginando que sim.

Comment: Você entendeu para ter campo Date, você tem que ter a datacompleta dia, mes e ano, quando você manipula somente o Ano, entra format();